# C++, ROOT framework : member method called periodically

Tags: c++, methods, root-framework

I have a class in my application displaying info.
I have to get those info from a server via SOAP.
Here's my class :

```
class InfoControl : public TGCompositeFrame {
private:
    //char*, int....
    bool bWorking;
public:
    InfoControl(const TGWindow *p);
    virtual ~InfoControl();
    void SetEventRate(char* evnum);
    void SetBufferRate(char* rate);
    void SetSuccess(char *s);
    void RequestInfo();
    ClassDef(InfoControl,1)  //useless : ROOT specific stuff
};
```

I would like `RequestInfo()` method to be called periodically as long as `bWorking` is true.
I red about `pthread` solutions, but don't know how to implement this. And maybe something more trivial is possible ?

Thanks in advance for help,
eo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out.
If someone has the same issue :

```
TTimer *timer = new TTimer();  
timer->Connect("Timeout()", "InfoControl", this, "RequestInfo()");  
timer->Start(1000, kFALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm... Mb

```
while (bWorking)
{
    RequestInfo();
    /* sleep os sleep function, or boost, or something else. 
    time - period to sleep.*/
    sleep(time);
}
```

or you want async call, with some timer?

Comment: I need to do other stuff in my program... I can't spend all the time looping.

Comment: There are 2 variants, i think, first is thread that do this periodically, or use std::async, second is use some async calling, for example boost::asio, but asio is network library...

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what kind of effects `RequestInfo()` should have on the outside since it is a `void`, but if it somehow talks to the outside and doesn't do exclusively some internal job (then running it in an extra thread would be fine) you should maybe rethink your design.

`bWorking` already is private, so an `InfoControl` knows when it changes. You could then use something like ROOT's Qt slots implementation (e.g. with a `TQObject`) to trigger a needed action only when `bWorking` changes (e.g. hook that into some `SetWorking()`).